# android external jar issue

Tags: java, android, jar, dex

In search of a way to upload an image, I added a lot of external JARs following this simple explanation:[using-multipartentity-in-android-applications](http://blog.tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2010/01/using-multipartentity-in-android-applications/)
But when I try co compile the code I'm getting an error:

```
[2012-12-14 11:37:55 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/ConnectionClosedException;
```

I have never used external libraries before. Can someone tell me how to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same class/classes may be defined in multiple libraries. That's why you are getting this error. You need to check which classes are overlapping and resolve the issue by re-organizing or removing some external libraries.

It might also be an eclipse issue. Try cleaning your project.

See the following threads:

[Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/myapp/R$array;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray)

[Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059719/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define)

[Error when building apk - "Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/Ad"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685864/error-when-building-apk-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-google-ads-ad?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

If you type

```
org.apache.http.auth.AUTH auth;
```

somewhere in your code, then select the `AUTH` part, right click it and hit Declarations > Workspace, you'll where this class is declared.  It's in android.jar, but in my project it was also in two separate versions of httpclient-4.x.x.jar (one had got added in as a dependency of another part of the project).

Removing the earlier version of httpclient-4.x.x.jar seems to have fixed this for me; you may find you have multiple libraries included in your project that declare this class (other than android.jar) and removing one or more will help too.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the src and gen folders and select Build Path > Remove from Build Path. then Right Click > Build Path > Use as Source Folder