# How to fix unable to execute dex multiple dex files define lcom google android vending licensing?

Tags: android, export, dex, lcom

My project was working fine before added com.google.android.vending.licensing package.
I also added all the libaray as required.but i am getting the above issue 
unable to execute dex multiple dex files define lcom google android vending licensing.

I googled a lot but nothing found any valid solution for this issue.

If anyone have idea please help me.

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685864/error-when-building-apk-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-google-ads-ad?rq=1
Maybe this can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by removing library.jar.Because i added library as well com.google.android.vending.licensing package also.
Thats why i was getting this issue.